# Adjective describing noun versus result of verb

Tags: adjetivos, desambiguación

Spanish noob here - I just encountered this on Duolingo:

> Felipe pinta su dormitorio azul.

Which translates to:

> Felipe is painting his bedroom blue.

This is very confusing for me - I'm not familiar with linguistic terms so I don't even know what to search for!  Basically, my problem is that I'm confused on how to say **Felipe is painting his bedroom (the color) blue** versus **Felipe is painting his blue bedroom**

That is, typically we would put the adjective after the noun, so "blue bedroom" is **dormitorio azul**.  But in this situation we're not using **azul** as an adjective to describe the bedroom, but as a descriptor of what is being done *with* the bedroom.

So: (1) how would one say *"Felipe is painting his blue bedroom"*, and (2) what are the rule(s) and/or context clues for knowing when an adjective is *describing* the noun versus the result of the action against the noun?

*As an aside - if anyone can leave a comment letting me know the right linguistic terms are, I'd appreciate it.  Can't search the web if you don't know the word you're searching for! :)*

Comment: The sentence in Spanish sounds a bit weird to me, I would have said _Felipe pinta su dormitorio **de** azul_. It is understandable that he is painting his bedroom with the color blue, since people generally just have one room, but strictly speaking can be confusing.

Comment: Maybe a better example is the bathroom.  Some houses have two of those.  *Quiero pintar el baño azul* might be ambiguous, although I agree with @fedorqui that "Quiero pintar el baño de azul" is more typical when painting it blue.  But to be clear I could say "Quiero pintar el baño de la planta baja."  In other words, I could use some other distinguishing feature to get my idea across. // I'm not sure which aspects of this you would like terminology for -- could you clarify? (I did add a tag that focuses on workarounds for ambiguities.) // Interesting question, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @fedorqui - Since comments are ephemeral I think you should move your comment to an answer.  Your simple distinction isn't in the existing answer.

Comment: @fedorqui yes, please add that as an answer.

Comment: @aparente001 In your bathroom example, if one is currently blue and the other is red (say both just need to be repainted), how I would I say *"I'm wanting to paint the blue bathroom"* (if I'm correct *"Quiero pintar el bano de azul"* is "I want to paint this the color blue" (not literal of course)

Comment: Sorry, I believe that's backwards.  Okay, we've got two different colored bathrooms, and I want to paint the blue one: "Quiero pintar el baño azul."  Now I'm standing in one of the bathrooms with my partner and the context shows which one I want to paint: "Quiero pintar el baño de azul" -- I want to change the color to blue (from whatever color it was).  (Granted, the first sentence -- Quiero pintar el baño azul" is a little weird.)

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it - thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the English language —where that distinction is possible via the ordering of the adjective—, in Spanish we do not have something so straight-forward to convey what is blue (the old bedroom or the same one after getting painted)

The way to say so without confusions would be

> ***Felipe pinta su dormitorio, el de color azul*** 
> Felipe paints his blue bedroom

vs

> ***Felipe pinta de azul su dormitorio*** 
>   Felipe paints his bedroom blue

Also if Felipe walks into a paint shop asking for advice, any Spanish speaking employee will know what he means if he says:

> **¿Qué marca de pintura me recomienda?** 
>     **Quiero pintar de verde mi dormitorio azul**
>
> I want to paint green my blue bedroom

Comment: That’s still confusing, to me the examples you give are reversed.   Fedorqui’s comment is correct ‘pintar algo de azul’ = to paint something blue

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, (got interrupted and lost the focus there)